# Update and Insert statements in one stored Procedure and only one works

Tags: .net, sql, insert-update

I have a table from which the data cannot essentially be removed.
So whenever I update a record, I have to preserve the previous record and copy the new details in a new row.
I have created a stored procedure for this, what it does is:

1. Updates the previous record with today's date to show that it expired today
2. Inserts the parameters which I have passed to it into a new row.

Now when I execute this procedure in SQL Server 2008, it executes perfectly showing that 2 rows are effected.
But when I call it from my program (its an MVC application), only updates occur - no inserts.

There are no errors or exception while execution.
The number of rows returned from `ExecuteNonQuery()` is 1.

Does anyone have any idea, what could possibly be the issue?

Following is the kind of thing m doing

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_ABC                              
(
@Primarykey int,
@Desc varchar(2000),
@Actor varchar(10),
@txtCreatedBy char(6),
@dtEfectiveEnd datetime                       
)                              
AS                              
BEGIN 
DECLARE @currentTime DATETIME, @intDeclarationID int
SET @currentTime = GETDATE()

SELECT @intDeclarationID = (MAX([intDeclarationId])+1) FROM tbl_ABC                      
BEGIN TRY            
UPDATE tbl_ABC                      
SET [dtEffectiveEnd] = GETDATE()
    ,[txtLastModifiedBy] = @txtCreatedBy
    ,[dtLastModifiedBy] = GETDATE()                  
 WHERE intDeclarationId = @Primarykey 

INSERT INTO tbl_ABC                      
       (
        [intDeclarationId]
       ,[txtDeclarationDesc]
       ,[txtActor]           
       ,[dtCreated]
       ,[txtCreatedBy]
       ,[dtLastModifiedBy]
       ,[txtLastModifiedBy]
       ,[dtEffectiveEnd]
           )                      
 VALUES                      
(
@intDeclarationID,
@Desc,
@Actor,
@currentTime,
@txtCreatedBy,
@currentTime,
@txtCreatedBy,
@dtEfectiveEnd 
)
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage
END CATCH
END
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide a snapshot of your stored procedure. The problem is not in the code, but in the stored procedure where you are not separating the result returned by the insert statement and the result returned by the updated statement. Your SP would give a better idea in this case. Can you please provide the same.